Pytesseract TesseractError: Unable to Load Language Files
I am trying to use pytesseract in my system. But I am getting the following error message
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file /opt/homebrew/share/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')

I am using an M1 MacBook Pro and installed the tesseract engine using brew
brew install tesseract
I also installed the lang files using the following command
brew install tesseract-lang
The TESSDATA_PREFIX seems to point to the correct location
/opt/homebrew/share/
I also ensured that the language files are present in the correct directory
ls /opt/homebrew/share/tessdata/
This is the result of the above command
LICENSE                  ceb.traineddata          eng.traineddata          gle.traineddata          jav.traineddata          lit.traineddata          osd.traineddata          snum.traineddata         tha.traineddata
README.md                ces.traineddata          enm.traineddata          glg.traineddata          jpn.traineddata          ltz.traineddata          pan.traineddata          spa.traineddata          tir.traineddata
afr.traineddata          chi_sim.traineddata      epo.traineddata          grc.traineddata          jpn_vert.traineddata     mal.traineddata          pdf.ttf                  spa_old.traineddata      ton.traineddata
amh.traineddata          chi_sim_vert.traineddata equ.traineddata          guj.traineddata          kan.traineddata          mar.traineddata          pol.traineddata          sqi.traineddata          tur.traineddata
ara.traineddata          chi_tra.traineddata      est.traineddata          hat.traineddata          kat.traineddata          mkd.traineddata          por.traineddata          srp.traineddata          uig.traineddata
asm.traineddata          chi_tra_vert.traineddata eus.traineddata          heb.traineddata          kat_old.traineddata      mlt.traineddata          pus.traineddata          srp_latn.traineddata     ukr.traineddata
aze.traineddata          chr.traineddata          fao.traineddata          hin.traineddata          kaz.traineddata          mon.traineddata          que.traineddata          sun.traineddata          urd.traineddata
aze_cyrl.traineddata     configs                  fas.traineddata          hrv.traineddata          khm.traineddata          mri.traineddata          ron.traineddata          swa.traineddata          uzb.traineddata
bel.traineddata          cos.traineddata          fil.traineddata          hun.traineddata          kir.traineddata          msa.traineddata          rus.traineddata          swe.traineddata          uzb_cyrl.traineddata
ben.traineddata          cym.traineddata          fin.traineddata          hye.traineddata          kmr.traineddata          mya.traineddata          san.traineddata          syr.traineddata          vie.traineddata
bod.traineddata          dan.traineddata          fra.traineddata          iku.traineddata          kor.traineddata          nep.traineddata          script                   tam.traineddata          yid.traineddata
bos.traineddata          deu.traineddata          frk.traineddata          ind.traineddata          kor_vert.traineddata     nld.traineddata          sin.traineddata          tat.traineddata          yor.traineddata
bre.traineddata          div.traineddata          frm.traineddata          isl.traineddata          lao.traineddata          nor.traineddata          slk.traineddata          tel.traineddata
bul.traineddata          dzo.traineddata          fry.traineddata          ita.traineddata          lat.traineddata          oci.traineddata          slv.traineddata          tessconfigs
cat.traineddata          ell.traineddata          gla.traineddata          ita_old.traineddata      lav.traineddata          ori.traineddata          snd.traineddata          tgk.traineddata

The eng.traineddata file which is what I want to primarily use is located in the directory
I also ensured that the prefix is exported in the zsh file
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew/share/
I double checked by looking into the file. I also reloaded the configuration settings by running source ~/.zshrc
Even after all of this I am getting the error message. I installed pytesseract inside a conda environment using pip and installed the tesseract engine using brew. I am not sure anymore what I am doing wrong.

set TESSDATA_PREFIX to /opt/homebrew/share/ but you show us they are in different location: /opt/homebrew/share/tessdata/
